# Php beginners questions, how can I exclude a folder in this script

Tags: php

can somebody help me? I use below script and it works but I want to exclude folders. If there are any better scripts out there that's also fine, I tried a lot but in combination with magento its a bit hard for me to understand. So the goal is to copy a folder to another folder including symlinks and everying inside the folders. Problem with this script is that he copies inside the same folder and then creates a loop

```
    $source = Mage::getBaseDir();
    $dest = Mage::getStoreConfig('Setupstaging_options/product_page/stagingfolder');
    mkdir($dest, 0755);
    foreach (
    $iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
    if ($item->isDir()) {
    mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }    else {
    copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do not copy, --> exclude :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the name of the folders you want to skip:

```
$exclude_dirs = array("onedir", "twodir"); // List of directory names to exclude
$source = Mage::getBaseDir();
$dest = Mage::getStoreConfig('Setupstaging_options/product_page/stagingfolder');
mkdir($dest, 0755);
foreach ($iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST) as $item) {
    if ($item->isDir() && !in_array($item->getFilename(), $exclude_dirs)) {  // If this Dir's name is not in $exclude_dirs
        mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
    else {
        copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use this condition :

```
 if ($item->isDir()) {
     if($item->getSubPathName() =! "your path directory to exclude"){
         mkdir($dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
     }           
 } else {
     copy($item, $dest . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $iterator->getSubPathName());
 }
```